# Angular2 getting route data with routes url?

Tags: angular, router

I got a constant array of routes called `AppRoutes` that contains all routes of my app. I wrote a function called `getRoutesAuth(path)` that uses the the `path` parameter to iterate through the `AppRoutes` array, returning an array of the data property of the routes of `path`. Is there a built in way to get a route's data property by a given path?

Comment: Did you ever work this out @max-solid?

Comment: @Spikeh nope ... but working on a way of solving this ... after managing it I'll answer this question .. but it could take some time since I've to finish other things first...

Comment: Did you finally find your solution?

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
{path: '/route', component: MyComponent ,data: { //data}}
```

use ActivatedRoute service to retreive data :

```
export class MyComponent {
constrcutor(private route :ActivatedRoute){}    

    ngOnInit() {
      this.route.data
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          // data
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not want to access the data of the current activated route. I need a function that searches for **any** route specified by the parameter `path` of the above described function I use that returns the data of this specified route.

Comment: why you want that ?

Comment: cause I have permissions and roles specified in lots of the routes data properties. With my function above I read all needed permissions and roles of the routes I specify in the parameter of the function. I can use this information returned by the function to only show navigation buttons (with a routerLink) inside the template of any component to the user if he is authorized to access the route and hide others that he is not authorized to activate.

Comment: Is there a way to use a url like `path/to/somewhere` to get the data property of each route used for this path?

Comment: @MaxSolid frankly I don`t know. I hope you find a solution